# Multiple mongoose find related queries, how to simplify to do only one?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Basically the problem is that doing multiple mongo queries to multiple models for processing data, is causing Timeouts and performance problems when the data is big. I need to improve the code performance. Is there any way to do a single aggregate or something related that queries to those multiples tables and accept before the next stage, do a map with the data obtained in the current stage of the aggregate as shown in my example code block ?.

```
return Foo.findOne({ id: 123asd })
 .then(foundFoo => {
   return Bar.find({ 'prop': foundFoo.someProp })
      .then(foundBars => {
        const neededArrayForNextFind = foundBars.map(bar => bar.neededProp);
        return AnotherFoo.find({
               'someProp': {'$in' : neededArrayForNextFind} 
            }).then(foundAnotherFoo => { 
              return doOtherStuffWithFoundData(foundFoo,foundBars,foundAnotherFoo);   
            })
      })
})
```

thank you all!

Comment: You may use populate the get the related child documents with parent documents.
Can you post your real model codes?

Comment: @SuleymanSah const schema = new Schema({
    index: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    type: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    speed: Number,
    mac: String,
    channel: {
        id: Number,
        frequency: Number,
        modulation: Number,
        width: Number,
        parent_iface: Number
    },
    stats_powers: {},
    imported: Boolean
});

export default DevicesModel.discriminator(DeviceType.Interface, schema);

Comment: @SuleymanSah const schema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    device_type: {
        type: String,
        enum : Object.values(DeviceType),
        required: true
    },
    icon: String,
    metric: String,
    logic: String,
    filter: String
});  export default model('anomaly', schema, 'anomaly');

Comment: @SuleymanSah const schema = new Schema({
    index: Number,
    ip: {
        type: String
    },
    mac: String,
    snmp_version: {
        type: String,
        enum: Object.values(SNMPVersion),
        default: SNMPVersion.SNMPv2c
    },
    docsis_version: {
        type: String,
    },
    username: String,
    password: String,
    community: String,
    stats_powers: {},
    interfaces: {
        down: Number,
        up: Number
    },
    imported: Boolean
}); 
export default DevicesModel.discriminator(DeviceType.Cablemodem, schema);

Comment: @SuleymanSah const schema = new Schema({
    client_id: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    short_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    tags: [String],
    t: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    v: [{}]
}); export default model('metric', schema, 'metric');

Comment: @SuleymanSah so the example code written originally before showing the Models, first fetches some data, then uses that fetched data, using the required prop to fetch other elements (via a .map in this case) from others collections.

Comment: @SuleymanSah more specifically, is there a way to define in the .aggregate mongoose aggregated method to, first fetch the InterfaceModel (first stage), base on that fetch other Cablemodems using that Interface (2nd stage), then fetch anomalies (3rd stage), then Metrics (4th stage)? and doing a .map before calling the next stage ? Will this single .aggregate method, be faster than having the .find separately ?